# Abrir Form2 lado a lado com o Form1 simultanemamente e fechar ou minimizar ambos simultaneamente

Tags: delphi

Preciso abrir 2 formulários simultaneamente um ao lado do outro e depois quando eu fechar ou minimizar algum deles, os 2 serem fechados/minimizados simultanemente. Procurei alguma ideia em vários sites e tudo que encontrei até agora foi o seguinte código que mostra o "Form2" no canto inferior direito da tela.

*Segue o código abaixo:*

```
// Form 1

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Form2.show;
end;


// Form 2

procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
Form2.TOP:= SCREEN.WorkAreaHeight - Form2.HEIGHT;
Form2.LEFT:=SCREEN.WorkareaWidth - Form2.WIDTH;
end;
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como atingir esse objetivo?

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, utiliza o componente [JvFormMagnet](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:JvFormMagnet.pas) ele faz esse trabalho, pra vc, basicamente você coloca um em cada form, seta a propriedade "FormMagnet" para true, e no segundo form vc seta "MainFormMagnet" para true tb. faça alguns testes e veja a magica!

Answer (score 0):

Se você utiliza MDI, pode encontrar a resposta
http://www.activedelphi.com.br/forum/viewtopic.php?t=30848&sid=d8bdb4bfa5d84ebab6d19c0412514cd4

Para o caso de utilizar form, acredito que há como controlar.
Alguns detalhes que podem de auxiliar neste caso.
1) você precisará saber o tamanho total da tela do monitor
2) o tamanho de cada form
3) descontar do tamanho total cada um dos tamanhos que quer dispor da janela

Comment: Eu queria via utilizando form mesmo. Msm assim, obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 0):

Talvez uma nova abordagem seja mais eficiente.

1 - Você tem a 1 tela que se chama form1

2 - Você tem a 2 tela que se chama form2

3 - Crie uma terceira tela com 2 panels, cada um com as dimensões do form1 e form2

4 - No formshow desta tela (form3), Faça um create no form1 colocando o parent para panel1. Depois faça um create no form2 colocando o parent para panel2.

Será criado os formulários dentro de cada panel.

Espero que ajude.